# Is there any an issue with the file name openjdk-8-jdk-headless?

Tags: java, python-3.x, apache-spark, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install *Spark* which requires Java with using

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
```

And I get an error after it.

> E: Failed to fetch [http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u252-b09-1~18.04_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u252-b09-1%7E18.04_amd64.deb)  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
> E: Failed to fetch [http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u252-b09-1~18.04_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u252-b09-1%7E18.04_amd64.deb)  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]

Is there any problem with the servers?

I am doing this on Google Colab.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless` ?

Comment: Anyway, those two URLs do indeed return 404.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should update your local version of the package catalog.

```
sudo apt update
```

After the above synchronisation step, you can re-issue the command

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
```

Thereby, it will download the latest version of `openjdk-8-jdk-headless`. There is an updated package in the [repository](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/). It has the version **`8u342-b07`**. Note the difference.

See also this [direct link](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u342-b07-0ubuntu1%7E18.04_amd64.deb) here to download a `.deb` package.:

Comment: Thanks. This was extactly the solution.

Comment: is there any way to download the openjdk-8-jdk-headless version directly?